# date column truncated when selected against

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am inserting the below values into a column with a "date" datatype.

```
2021-09-20 06:19:00
2021-09-20 12:22:00
```

The related file is a CSV and inserts successfully using the copy command.

When I select against the column from "dbeaver" the output reflects:

```
2021-09-20
2021-09-20
```

The time is missing.

Is the time there really, but there is some format mask I need to use to display it or, am I using the wrong datatype and the value is truncated at insert?

Comment: The `date` datatype only includes the date. Use `timestamp` to include date and time.

Comment: @sj95126 Thanks, have just dropped table - recreated it with a timestamp column, selecting against it still results in a truncated date format despite there being a date and time inserted.

Comment: Could be a dbeaver issue, did you try another client (like psql) ?

Comment: To your question add the query you are using.

Comment: @FrankHeikens I did try psql and actually it is sorted now. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the DDL to swap out the date datatype for timestamp and used psql to verify that it resolved the issue. Thank you to all that answered.

Comment: You know you can accept your own answer to settle this question, right?

Comment: I did not realise I had to accept it - I have now though, thanks.

Comment: You don't *have* to. It marks the question as resolved, and helps keeping stats tidy.